# Need to read from 4,5 tables from a database and then to write it to multiple tables in 2 databases using spring batch, spingboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am new to spring batch and I need to write a job where I am reading from 5 tables from database 1 and then writing it to multiple tables of Database 2 and Database 3 mostly with very little need of processing if at all. How can I go ahead with this.

What kind of reader and writer should I use and also will I be like querying all the data in 1 go using a select query which selects data from all 5 tables in 1 go and then writing it to DB2 and DB3.
If I am going with this, then I will have to create an entity which is a combination of all 5 DB tables I am reading from ?
I am extremely new to this so a detailed explanation assuming that I have no knowledge on this would really help.
Thanks in advance !